# Getting Error while compiling: Stack too deep

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle, solc

Here is my code i have array not 16 variables in a function please help where i am wrong.

```
struct Escrow {
     bytes16 contractID;

     uint256 sellingTokenAmt;
     uint256 feeAmtInSellingToken;
     uint256 arbitrationFees;
     uint256 paymentWindowInSeconds;
     uint256 contractLifespanInSec;
     uint256 disputeWindowInSeconds;


     uint256 buyingTokenAmt;
     uint256 buyerAddress1Amt;
     uint256 buyerAddress2Amt;
     uint256 buyerAddress3Amt;
     uint256 createdAt;
     uint256 updatedAt;
     uint256 disputedAt;

     address sellerAddress;
     address buyerAddress1;
     address buyerAddress2;
     address buyerAddress3;
     address feeAddress;
     address arbitratorAddress;
     address sellingToken;

     string buyingToken;
     bool isDisputed;
     bool createdBy;
     string sellerPaymentDetails;

}

function createEscrow(bytes16 _contractId, uint256[] calldata _intValues,
     string calldata _buyingToken,
     address[] calldata _addresses,
     address token,
     string calldata _sellerPaymentDetails
   ) payable external    {   
 bytes32 _tradeHash =  keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_contractId));
 Escrow storage escrow = escrows[_tradeHash]; 
 uint256 tokenBalance = ERC20Interface(token).balanceOf(msg.sender);

require(escrow.contractID!=_contractId, "Already in Trading.");
require (_intValues[0] > 0, "Please add valid amount");
require (_intValues[0] > 0, "Please add valid amount");
require(tokenBalance >=_intValues[0], "Insufficient balance.");
require(ERC20Interface(token).transferFrom(_addresses[0], address(this), _intValues[0]));

escrows[_tradeHash] = Escrow(_contractId, _intValues[0], _intValues[1], _intValues[2], _intValues[3], _intValues[4], _intValues[5],
_intValues[6], _intValues[7], _intValues[8], _intValues[9], now, now, now ,_addresses[0], _addresses[1], _addresses[2],
_addresses[3], _addresses[4], _addresses[5], token, _buyingToken, false, true, _sellerPaymentDetails);
totlaEscrows++;

  emit Created (_tradeHash);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says it all, you need to break down your struct data. Either separate it to different structs, contracts or keep some of the data offchain (database), make connection/ linking with unique parameter and save that unique parameter into the struct.

Another solution is what I did for another project I had to save many variables including files for single person so I just uploaded everything to IPFS and saved only the IPFS hash into the person data in my smart contract. (same principle as storing database ID in your smart contract)

Comment: To split code in structs is right way or not?